# Create Subscriber in Exact Target from External Salesforce Org

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, soap-api

We have a simple requirement of creating a subscriber in an Exact Target Org from an external Salesforce Org.
The requirement is on webpage on click of a sign-up button the user email id will be used to create the Subscriber in Exact Target Org.

We could figure out the way to get the Auth Toker using REST Call to https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken
The next step would be to use this Auth Token to create the subscriber.

Our doubts are:
1)  Can this be done using REST API call?
2)  Is we need to use SOAP, is there a necessity to create a middle-layer application?
3)  If not, has anyone done this kind of Integration and help us on the steps to proceed?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can't use REST API to create a subscriber. There are 2 ways this can be done in my understanding -

1. Using SOAP API
2. Using Fuel SDK (https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/fuel-sdks/subscribers/subscriber-create.html)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after a lot of research we found out the following

1. Using the WSDL provided by Exact Target, the Apex Classes generated do not work properly. We struggled a lot and finally gave up.
2. Approach, we took was to use the SOAP structure required for the request and generate the same via plain apex class (not generated by wsdl) and make the request using HTTP POST.
3. Instead of using the user name and password in the SOAP xml as directed in ET site (https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/soap-api/creating-a-subscriber.html ) we are trying to use the OAUTH Token in the header for the SOAP request, we ares till working on the approach to work completely, will keep everyone updated.